# I am getting NullPointerException when getFacade().create(current) is executed

Tags: jpa, glassfish-3, jta, entitymanager, facade

My PujaController.java:

```
public class PujaController implements Serializable {

private Puja current;
private DataModel items = null;
@EJB
private jpa.sessions.PujaFacade ejbFacade;
private PaginationHelper pagination;
private int selectedItemIndex;

public PujaController() {
}

public Puja getSelected() {
    if (current == null) {
        current = new Puja();
        current.setPujaPK(new jpa.entities.PujaPK());
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
    }
    return current;
}

private PujaFacade getFacade() {
    return ejbFacade;
}


public String creaPuja(Subasta subasta) {
    try {
        current = new Puja();
        current.setPujaPK(new jpa.entities.PujaPK());
        selectedItemIndex = -1;

        current.getPujaPK().setNroDePuja(0); //AUTO_INCREMENT
        Postor postor = AuthenticationPhaseListener.getLoggedInPostor();
        current.getPujaPK().setEmail(postor.getEmail());
        current.getPujaPK().setSubastaId(subasta.getSubastaId());

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = cal.getTime();
        current.setFechaDePuja(new java.sql.Timestamp(now.getTime()));
        current.setMontoAPagar(BigDecimal.ONE);
        current.setMontoDePuja(BigDecimal.TEN);
        current.setNroDePujas(0);
        current.setPagoAcumulado(BigDecimal.ONE);

        getFacade().create(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PujaCreated"));
        return "Puja";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
}


public String prepareCreate() {
    current = new Puja();
    current.setPujaPK(new jpa.entities.PujaPK());
    selectedItemIndex = -1;
    return "Create";
}

public String create() {
    try {
        current.getPujaPK().setNroDePuja(0); //AUTO_INCREMENT
        current.getPujaPK().setEmail(current.getPostor().getEmail());
        current.getPujaPK().setSubastaId(current.getSubasta().getSubastaId());
        getFacade().create(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PujaCreated"));
        return prepareCreate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

My SubastaController.java:

```
public class SubastaController implements Serializable {

private Subasta current;
private DataModel items = null;
@EJB
private jpa.sessions.SubastaFacade ejbFacade;
private PaginationHelper pagination;
private int selectedItemIndex;

public SubastaController() {
}

public Subasta getSelected() {
    if (current == null) {
        current = new Subasta();
        selectedItemIndex = -1;
    }
    return current;
}

private SubastaFacade getFacade() {
    return ejbFacade;
}


public String preparePuja() {
    current = (Subasta) getItems().getRowData();
    selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() +    getItems().getRowIndex();
    return "Puja";
}

public String pujar() {
    try {
        getFacade().edit(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("SubastaUpdated"));
        PujaController pc = new PujaController();
        pc.creaPuja(current);
        return "Puja";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
}

public String prepareCreate() {
    current = new Subasta();
    selectedItemIndex = -1;
    return "Create";
}

public String create() {
    try {
        getFacade().create(current);
        JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("SubastaCreated"));
        return prepareCreate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Hi, trying to learn some JSF, EntityManager API, I getting stuck here: When pujar() is executed, the subasta get updated successfully and then the creaPuja(current) in pujaController is executed. The creaPuja(current) is ok until getFacade().create(current); is execute and give me a NullPointerException. The current object is created and the key are set. I do not find the way to get the references to the Entity Manager to get successfully create puja. I include the Facade java file also. If you can provide some code to explain the problem would be great!!!

The pujaFacade.java:

```
public class PujaFacade extends AbstractFacade<Puja> {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "subasta701WPU")
private EntityManager em;

protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public PujaFacade() {
    super(Puja.class);
}
```

}

The abstractFacade.java:

```
public abstract class AbstractFacade<T> {
private Class<T> entityClass;

public AbstractFacade(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected abstract EntityManager getEntityManager();

public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

public void edit(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

public void remove(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(getEntityManager().merge(entity));
}

@PostConstruct
public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}

@PostConstruct
public List<T> findAll() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}

public List<T> findRange(int[] range) {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0]);
    q.setFirstResult(range[0]);
    return q.getResultList();
}

public int count() {
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    javax.persistence.criteria.Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
    cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
    javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
    return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
}
```

}

Here is the Exception:

```
INFO: java.lang.NullPointerException
at jsf.PujaController.creaPuja(PujaController.java:146)
at jsf.SubastaController.pujar(SubastaController.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Yes, the getFacade() in null. My question is how I move or assign the current object to getFacade(). There are a member ejbFacade of type PujaFacade, but I need ejbFacade get the value of current (Puja object) so getFacade will not be null. Thank you ...

Comment: Yes, the getFacade() in null. My question is how I move or assign the current object to getFacade(). There are a member ejbFacade of type PujaFacade, but I need ejbFacade get the value of current (Puja object) so getFacade will not be null

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of **getFacade()** and **current** at the point that the exception is thrown.

Also, can you please post the stack trace from the exception.

Note: In my experience NullPointerException are the result of accessing a method from a null object.  In this case, that would mean getFacade() is returning null.

**Update:**
After reviewing your code I am not sure. You never set ejbFacade in PujaController or SubastaController, but are able to access it in SubastaController but not in PujaController.
Try comparing the jpa.sessions.SubastaFacade implementation with the jpa.sessions.PujaFacade implementation and see if you are missing anything.

For example, does PujaFacade need a @Stateless before the class definition?  Should the unit name in @PersistenceContext(unitName = "subasta701WPU") be changed?

You may also want to read these:

[Getting Started with Java EE 6 Applications](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/javaee-gettingstarted.html)

[The Java Persistence API - A Simpler Programming Model for Entity Persistence](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jpa-137156.html)

[A Wikipedia page with some good samples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans)

Let us know how it turns out.